# Mocking Newtonsoft.Json When Unit Testing

Tags: c#, unit-testing, exception, json.net, nunit

I'm currently testing a class that reads an embedded json file, deserialises and loads it into my DI container. Here is a tl;dr of the code, omitting error handling:

```
private readonly IAssemblyManager _assemblyManager;
private readonly IContainerRegistry _containerRegistry

public void Load(string resourceName)
{
    string json = _assemblyManager.LoadResource(resourceName);

    IConfiguration config = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Configuration>(json);

    _containerRegistry.RegisterInstance<IConfiguration>(config);
}
```

I'm using NUnit and Moq to test and I'm fairly new to the testing game. I want to know the best approach to testing the `JsonConvert` method, I've had to write wrappers for some of my tests but would be absolutely devastated if I had to do it here. This is the most downloaded NuGet package, surely people have come across this issue and have a decent solution. I've used [`System.IO.Abstractions`](https://github.com/System-IO-Abstractions/System.IO.Abstractions) to allow me to test my file access code, I would have expected there would be something similar for `Newtonsoft.Json`.

Other potential workarounds could be to have my assembly manager doing the deserialisation:

```
public interface IAssemblyManager
{
    T LoadResource<T>(string resourceName);
}
```

But for my application I want to use the `IAssemblyManager` to load sql & json, I don't really want it being responsible for deserialising anything. And I've also just moved my problem from one class to another.

Comment: You say you want to test JsonConvert but you wanted to say that you want to test without a dependency on JsonConvert correct? Aka mocking it away. That is good practice but personally i never had the need to mock it away. Even in your example i don't see the need of getting JsonConvert mocked.

Comment: I'm not particualrly bothered about testing the `JsonConvert.Deserialize` method, but I am interested in mocking its behaviour. As far as I'm concerned it can either return a value, return null or throw an exception, I would like to address these scenarios in my tests. I have some code after the object has been registered with the container to verify it was registered, I don't really want to be adhering to the rules of `Newtonsoft.Json` in my tests, I don't want to treat it as concrete :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no official dependency injection package for Newtonsoft.JSON. To test your code, there is no way around creating wrappers, unless you find a mocking framework that mocks static methods.